# how to use declared variable to select data from another table in case when condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I made select query in which i want to select data based on condition.For this i declared one variable and set value of that variable in else part.I want to use that variable for further select in same else part how can i achieve this?Please Help

```
declare @stateid int
select CASE WHEN MstCustomerAddressInfo.StateId is null 
                  THEN 24 
        ELSE set @stateid = MstCustomerAddressInfo.StateId
             select mststate.statecode from mststate where MstState.StateId = @stateid 
       END AS StateCode
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have `SET` inside a `CASE` expression. Even you can't have multiple statements.

Same query you can write as following.

```
declare @stateid int 

select CASE 
         WHEN MstCustomerAddressInfo.StateId is null THEN 24 
         ELSE 
       -- set @stateid = MstCustomerAddressInfo.StateId 
       (select mststate.statecode 
        from   mststate 
        where  MstState.StateId = MstCustomerAddressInfo.StateId) 
       END AS StateCode 
from   [Your_Table]
```